# Unable to use DialStyle QML Type

Tags: qt, qml

I use Dial in qt5. Unable to use DialStyle QML Type. Is there any example?

I tried to set

```
import QtQuick.Extras 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4


Dial {
            id: idDial
            width: 100; height: 100
            anchors.centerIn: parent

            style: DialStyle {
                background: Background {
                    width: 100; height: 100

                }

                handle: Rectangle {
                    width: 50; height: 50
                    color: "yellow"
                }

                handleInset: 50

            }
        }
```

Should i enable animations also for the style components ?

Comment: What kind of animation do you want in particular? your question is very imprecise

Comment: @eyllanesc: With the code mentioned above, the dial does not function. For other components like button, we just need to set items to properties, the functionality would work. Here it does not.

Comment: Explain better, I do not understand anything, I have changed Background to Rectangle, obviously importing using `import QtQuick 2.7` and setting a color and I see that it works: https://imgur.com/a/UMw5p

Comment: Oh... my `handleInset` property was causing the handle to be centered to the background. Also the size of handle was also a problem. Now I reduced the size of handle rect, and removed handleInset. It works fine. Thanks :)

Comment: Do not change the title of your question to indicate that you have solved it, publish an answer and mark it as correct.